# How can I programmatically set the inputs and outputs of a Matlab Function block to other simulink blocks?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to programatically create several Matlab Function blocks to have their input set to the output of a Mux block, and their output set to the signal port of an Output Switch block.

I've created some basic Simulink models in the past using the add_block and add_line functions, but it seems Matlab Function blocks work differently.

I know what I'm trying to do can be achieved since I've done it manually, but I need to achieve this programatically to create large models.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by set? Do you mean connect the input (resp. output) to the output (resp. input) of another block?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Consider for example a Simulink model with a constant block, a MATLAB Function and a Scope block. Try the following:

```
add_line('untitled','Constant/1','MATLAB Function/1')
add_line('untitled','MATLAB Function/1','Scope/1')
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! My mistake was how I was refering to the ports in the function block (RConn1 | LConn1). My bad, since I just recently started learning Simulink by example.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to point me to a resource so that lets me discover things such as the port names of different blocks etc?

Comment: Check the [documentation for `add_line`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/add_line.html): "Most block ports are identified by numbering the ports from top to bottom or from left to right, such as `'Gain/1'` or `'Sum/2'`. Enable, Trigger, State, and Action ports are identified by name, such as `'subsystem_name/Enable'`, `'subsystem_name/Trigger'`, `'Integrator/State'`, or `'if_action_subsystem_name/Ifaction'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check the documenation.